Android studio installer not updating the software but installing a fresh version of it separately
My android studio won't update from old to new version. Rather it is attempting to create another folder to install the new version without removing the older version.
The location it is suggesting to install the software in is C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio2 but it is not the location of my current install.
I see that even while trying to install it in the folder of old version, it says to choose an empty folder.

Tried installing in the current version folder but the popup says that an empty folder is needed for the installation.
FYI- I am currently on version - Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2
